# Updating invalid timestamps in Google BigQuery table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My table has a few invalid timestamps that I think are too precise (maybe beyond microseconds) for BigQuery.

When I tried updating the table with the following query using Standard SQL:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET event_time = TIMESTAMP(DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(CAST(SUBSTR(SAFE_CAST(UNIX_MILLIS(event_time) AS string),1,13) AS int64))))
WHERE DATE(logtime) BETWEEN "2018-03-21" AND "2018-03-23"
    AND event_time IS NOT NULL
```

I get the invalid timestamp error:

```
Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of 1521738691071000064 microseconds relative to the Unix epoch. The range of valid timestamp values is [0001-01-1 00:00:00, 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999]; error in writing field event_time
```

I think the problem is the `SET event_time =` part, but I don't know how to get around setting the values in the `event_time` column without referring to it.

Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What does "invalid timestamp" mean?  Obviously if the data is being stored in a column whose datatype is `timestamp`, then BigQuery doesn't think the values are invalid.

Comment: I can't provide sample data from the `event_time` field, because simply querying its raw data returns the same invalid timestamp error. Data is only returned if I transform it using the timestamp transformation I used in my `update` query. However, my desired results would look something like this: `2018-03-23 21:06:46.116 UTC`

Comment: Can you post the results of `SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(a)
FROM your_table  a
LIMIT 1`

Comment: Felipe, when I try to run the query, I get the following error: `Invalid timestamp value: 1521749062783000064`

Comment: Please file a ticket in the BigQuery issue tracker - support might be able to fix it. In the meantime: Try running queries with #legacySQL, that might work

Comment: I've already filed a ticket, and Google Support's advice wasn't helpful.

Comment: is this a public ticket? can I take a look? I'm glad to see you were able to solve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necessity is the mother of invention. For anyone who has a similar issue, I've figured out a workaround.

1. Create a new table of the affected rows (include this in the `WHERE` clause: `LENGTH(CAST(UNIX_MILLIS(event_time) as string)) > 13`, while transforming the
   invalid timestamp into a valid format using `TIMESTAMP(DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(CAST(SUBSTR(SAFE_CAST(UNIX_MILLIS(event_time) AS string),1,13) AS int64))))`
2. Delete the affected rows from the original table using the `WHERE` clause mentioned above.
3. Insert all rows from the new table back into the original table.

A lot more work, but it should do the trick.